# mod_rewrite condition and rule effects POST vars in a bad way

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have 2 domains `mydomain.com` and `mydomain.org`. The site lives at `mydomain.org` so I want any attempt to `mydomain.com` to resolve to `mydomain.org`.

The following mod_rewrite rule that works to a degree.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

After I implemented it and tested it I felt it was doing everything I needed until I submitted a form with method="post".

For some reason, this mod_rewrite trashes my _POST vars

I am working solely from mydomain.org (which is the TLD I want the site to resolve from and where I submitted the form from).

Does anyone know of an adjustment to my condition and rule to not lose the _POST vars?

---

I identified something interesting. I plugged-in the HTTP Live Headers add-on in Firefox. When I use the mod_rewrite I get an "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" and when I turn off mod_rewrite I get a "HTTP/1.1 200 OK". The same page and PHP code behind is used. Again, when I have the mod_rewrite directives turned off, the _POST data comes through. When I turn on the mod_rewrite directives, the _POST data does not come through.

MOD_REWRITE **Turned Off**:

```
http://dashausmuseum.org/subscribe.html

POST /subscribe.html HTTP/1.1
Host: dashausmuseum.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://dashausmuseum.org/subscribe.html
Cookie: __utma=74430599.461726749.1312575846.1312897084.1312899646.5; __utmz=74430599.1312575846.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=1.480711209.1312899756.1312979975.1312981669.5; __utmz=1.1312981669.5.5.utmcsr=dashausmuseum.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/directions.html; __utmb=1.9.10.1312981669; PHPSESSID=7f4a74d7fde56cf901aa85511410b7f6; __utmc=1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 60
email=abc&firstName=&lastName=&address=&phone=&submit=Submit

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2011 13:18:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.3.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.4
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 5420
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

MOD_REWRITE **Turned On**:

```
http://dashausmuseum.org/subscribe.html

POST /subscribe.html HTTP/1.1
Host: dashausmuseum.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://dashausmuseum.org/subscribe.html
Cookie: __utma=74430599.461726749.1312575846.1312897084.1312899646.5; __utmz=74430599.1312575846.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=1.480711209.1312899756.1312979975.1312981669.5; __utmz=1.1312981669.5.5.utmcsr=dashausmuseum.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/directions.html; __utmb=1.10.10.1312981669; PHPSESSID=7f4a74d7fde56cf901aa85511410b7f6; __utmc=1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 60
email=xyz&firstName=&lastName=&address=&phone=&submit=Submit

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2011 13:20:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.3.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.4
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 5329
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Does anyone see anything in the HTTP Headers that gives a clue as to what is going on?

Comment: Does anyone see anything about each of the 3 directives that might be syntactically incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something else should be wrong, rewrite rules can't destroy _POST vars.

How are you setting/calling them in your code?

Comment: I am using PHP as code behind (referring to them as $_POST['element'], etc.). But what is interesting is that when I comment (#) out each of the 3 mod_rewrite lines in my .htaccess file, the form submits with the POST data. Yet, the moment I uncomment the 3 directives, the form does not submit and POST data.

Comment: Found a number of similar issues through a Google search. So it seems to be a problem. I changed everything over from _POST data to _GET data and it still does not work.

Comment: May be a cross-domain security issue if your form is calling http://domain.com/action.php from http://domain.org/form.html. Does this happens when you call .org/action.php from .org/form.html?

Comment: _POST data and _GET data are very different:The _GET datas are passed through the request uri (ie: "foo.php?bar=null", $_GET['bar'] will return "null") while the POST datas are sent by the browser through the headers.

Comment: I do not do any cross domain processing.

Answer (score 0):

There is some discussion about what should happen to a POST transaction in response to a 301 (or other) redirect.  [Here is one example](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/www/post-redirect.html)  where the author suggests it is "messy".

Is it possible your browser is converting the POST to a GET request?  Is it also possible the behavior is different in different browsers?

Comment: I tried it as both a _POST and a _GET in FF5, IE8, Opera11, Safari5 and Chrome. Did not work in any of them

Comment: I think the takeaway from the writeup I linked to, and my reading of some of the references (RFCs, etc.) provided is: when sending a redirect response to a POST request, you are at the mercy of the browser to do the right thing, and the right thing is probably not the behavior you want anyway.  Of note "the HTTP specification forbids the client to silently perform the redirected transaction."